# Array Comparision

Tags: arrays, vba, dynamic-arrays

I have a array with 8 columns and 42 rows B2 TO I43. I have to compare this array with other arrays in the same sheet so that every array have same values. I defined array1 Rang('B2;I43") and need to compare every other array of same size. how to that in VBA.
My code is

```
Sub driver()
Dim array1, array2, m, n
Set array1 = Range("B2,I43")
total_rows = 42
total_cols = 8
Set array2 = Range("B44:I85")

For i = 1 To total_rows
For j = 1 To total_cols
    If array1(i, j) = array2(i, j) Then
    array2.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    ElseIf array1(i, j) <> array2(i, j) Then
    array2.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3   
    End If
    Next j
    Next i          
End Sub
```

I want `array2` to point to other set of values. Every array start after 42 rows.

Comment: Can you define "POINT TO OTHER SET OF VALUES"?  Are you trying to copy values from array 1 to array 2?  Or from the cells B2:I43 to B44:I85?

Comment: First  I want to compare B2:I43  to B44:I85 after then I want to compare B2:I43 TO B86:I127( next 42 rows) and so on. So Initially array2 range is (  B44:I85) after that array2 range is (B86:I127) and so on..

Comment: So is this a case of adding an outer loop, outside of the two for..next statements?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Conditional formatting instead? Your suggested VBA code can easily be solved with conditional formatting by comparing each cell in array2 with the same cell in array1 and use colours to mark if the cells are equal or not

**Edit**
I have modified your code. Instead of using two ranges I have used an "row offset" for each array you have on your sheet. It then compares the cells from your source array (array1 in your code) with the cells that are found *next_array_offset* rows down. When the comparison has been made, the offset is increased with 42. The loop ends when there are no more values to be found.

Is this what you was looking for?

```
Sub driver()
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim source_row As Integer
    Dim source_col As Integer
    Dim total_rows As Integer
    Dim total_cols As Integer
    Dim next_array_offset As Integer

    source_row = 2   ' row B
    source_col = 2   ' col 2
    total_rows = 42
    total_cols = 8
    next_array_offset = 42  ' distance in rows to next array

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(source_row + next_array_offset, source_col).Value)
        For r = 0 To total_rows - 1
            For c = 0 To total_cols - 1
                If Cells(source_row + r, source_col + c) = Cells(source_row + next_array_offset + r, source_col + c) Then
                    Cells(source_row + next_array_offset + r, source_col + c).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                Else
                    Cells(source_row + next_array_offset + r, source_col + c).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            Next
        Next
        next_array_offset = next_array_offset + 42
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I have to develop it in VBA. All I need is after completing the comparison with one array, array2 will point to another array of same size

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It totally worked.

Comment: Hello, Can you please help me in defining the dynamic row for the same code. Instead of hard coding the rows (total_rows =42) is there any way the code can take no. of rows automatically, Now I have the data with no fixed numbers of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your main task is to define the ranges accurately. In the code below I've assumed it's every 42 rows until end of data. You simply iterate your 42-row test arrays and compare against the reference array. To do this you basically need two row variables: one for your test array and one for your reference array.

The quickest way would be to read the test data just once into one big array and to create two ranges (one with matches and one with mis-matches) and then colour them at the end of the routine.

I don't know your colour palette (and therefore the color indexes) so I've used the `.Color` property. You can adjust this to suit.

```
Const ROW_COUNT As Long = 42
Const COL_COUNT As Long = 8
Const START_ROW As Long = 2
Dim refArray As Variant, testArray As Variant
Dim rowSize As Long, r As Long, c As Long, i As Long
Dim cell As Range, yesRng As Range, noRng As Range

'Read data into arrays
With Sheet1
    'Find last row of data
    rowSize = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    'Adjust last row to be multiple of 42
    rowSize = Int((rowSize - START_ROW) / ROW_COUNT) * ROW_COUNT

    refArray = .Cells(START_ROW, "B").Resize(ROW_COUNT, COL_COUNT).Value2
    testArray = .Cells(START_ROW + ROW_COUNT, "B").Resize(rowSize, COL_COUNT).Value2
End With

'Compare test array with reference array
i = 1 'refArray row index
For r = 1 To UBound(testArray, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(testArray, 2)
        Set cell = Sheet1.Cells(r + START_ROW + ROW_COUNT - 1, c + 1)
        If testArray(r, c) = refArray(i, c) Then
            'It's a match so add to yes range
            If yesRng Is Nothing Then
                Set yesRng = cell
            Else
                Set yesRng = Union(yesRng, cell)
            End If
        Else
            'It's a miss so add to no range
            If noRng Is Nothing Then
                Set noRng = cell
            Else
                Set noRng = Union(noRng, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'Increment ref row index or set back to 1 if at 42
    i = IIf(i < ROW_COUNT, i + 1, 1)
Next

'Colour the ranges
If Not yesRng Is Nothing Then yesRng.Interior.Color = vbGreen
If Not noRng Is Nothing Then noRng.Interior.Color = vbRed
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.